# algebraic numbers with small norms

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Does there exist an algebraic number $\alpha$ such that
$$\left|\frac{\alpha^n+\alpha^n_1}{n!}\right|\sim_{n\to+\infty}\frac1{(n!)^2}$$ where $\alpha_1$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$?
Obviously $\alpha$ can not be a rational number.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something in the question. I edit it. But anyway your argument still works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any fixed nonzero complex numbers $z_1,\dotsc,z_m$, there are infinitely many $n$'s such that the arguments of $z_1^n,\dotsc,z_m^n$ all lie in $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$. This follows from Dirichlet's theorem on simultaneous diophantine approximation. For such $n$'s,
$$|z_1^n+\dotsb+z_m^n|\geq\Re(z_1^n+\dotsb+z_m^n)\geq\frac{|z_1|^n+\dotsb+|z_m|^n}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
In particular, the left hand side cannot be asymptotically $1/n!$, because the right hand side is exponentially small at worst.

In short, there is no $\alpha$ satisfying the requirements.

Comment: Nice answer for this question. I have a one more that is related. You could be interested in it :D

Comment: @joaopa: Please ask your related question in a separate post. I will look at it as time and mood permits :-)